# Kivy application lifecycle (widget duplicating itself on each redraw)

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I've been looking at Kivy as a way of dynamically drawing widgets driven from a web API hosted in the same application. I'm still very new to the topic and I've run into a problem with the lifecycle of the Kivy framework.
In summary what I'm trying to achieve is to send a kv string using an API call which is setup using Flask. Upon receiving the new kv string I attempt to unload the old view and load the new one. This works fine for anything trivial like buttons and simple layouts but I have a countdown timer widget which on each call duplicates its label and never properly clears down the view. It's almost like every time the kv string gets loaded it duplicates the widget object. I am obviously not clearing the view properly before attempting to load the new one but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I will post the full code first for the python app:

```
import threading

import datetime

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import Property, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, SmoothLine
from kivy.clock import Clock

from app_shell import AppShell
from _functools import partial
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from math import cos, sin, pi
from kivy.uix.layout import Layout

class CountdownTimer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TimerTicks(Widget):
    time = StringProperty()    
    running = BooleanProperty(False)
    countdown = 4520

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TimerTicks, self).__init__(**kwargs) 

        self.time = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(0, 0, 0)

        self.update()

        self.start()

    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = True
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

    def stop(self):
        if self.running:
            self.running = False
            print("timer stopped")
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)

    def destroy(self):
        print('TimerTicks destroy called')
        self.stop()

        parent = self.parent

        if parent is not None:
            self.parent.clear_widgets()

        print("i'm here")

    def update(self, *kwargs):
        print('update called')
        hours, mins_m = divmod(self.countdown, 3600)

        mins, secs = divmod(mins_m, 60)

        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, mins, secs)
        self.time = timeformat        

        if self.countdown == 0:
            self.stop()
        else:
            self.countdown -= 1        

        '''print('update called')
        mins, secs = divmod(self.countdown, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        self.time = timeformat        

        if self.countdown == 0:
            self.stop()
        else:
            self.countdown -= 1'''

    def reset(self, value):
        self.stop()

        print("reset with value {0}".format(value))

        self.time = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(0, 0, 0)

        self.countdown = value

        self.update()

        self.start()

class MainApp(App):
    temp_count = 0

    current_layout_name = "home.kv"
    welcome_message = "Not set"
    error_message = "Not set"
    current_layout = None

    def build(self):
        print('building app')

        self.address = ""
        self.port = 0        

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run_app_shell, args=    (self.on_to_gui_status_change, self.on_to_gui_layout_change,     self.on_to_gui_redraw))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()  # Starts the thread
        t.setName('appShellThread')  # Makes it easier to interact with the     thread later

        self.root = BoxLayout()

        self.view = Builder.load_file('layouts/home.kv')

        self.root.add_widget(self.view)

        return self.root

    def run_app_shell(self, on_to_gui_status_change,     on_to_gui_layout_change, on_to_gui_redraw):
        self.shell = AppShell(on_to_gui_status_change,     on_to_gui_layout_change, on_to_gui_redraw)

        self.address = self.shell.self_address
        self.port = self.shell.http_port

        self.welcome_message = "Welcome!\n------    ---------\n Get request to http://{0}:{1}/change_layout/name to change the     current layout".format(self.address, self.port)        

        self.shell.start()

    def on_stop(self):
        self.shell.close()

    def on_to_gui_layout_change(self, layout_name, layout):
        print('on_to_gui_layout_change called!')
        try:            
            cb = partial(self.change_kv, layout_name, layout)

            Clock.schedule_once(cb)            

        except Exception as exp:
            print ("exception {0}".format(exp)) 

    def change_kv(self, layout_name, layout, *args):
        try:                        
            for widget in self.root.walk(restrict=True):
                if hasattr(widget, 'destroy'):
                    widget.destroy()

            self.root.clear_widgets()

            self.current_layout_name = '{0}.kv'.format(layout_name)        

            if layout is not None:
                print('loading custom kv {0}'.format(layout))

                self.current_layout = layout
                del self.view
                self.view = Builder.load_string(layout)
            else:
                print('loading {0}.kv'.format(layout_name))

                self.current_layout = None

                self.view =     Builder.load_file('layouts/{0}.kv'.format(layout_name))            

            self.root.add_widget(self.view)            

            Builder.apply(self.root)

        except (SyntaxError) as e:
            print("exp 1 {0}".format(e))
            self.load_error_gui()
        except Exception as e:
            print("exp 2 {0}".format(e))
            self.load_error_gui()

    def load_error_gui(self):
        self.error_message = "Welcome!\n--------    -------\n Your previous layout could not be loaded!"

        for widget in self.root.walk(restrict=True):
            if hasattr(widget, 'destroy'):
                widget.destroy()

        self.root.clear_widgets()

        self.current_layout_name = '{0}.kv'.format("error")

        print('loading {0}.kv'.format("error"))

        self.view = Builder.load_file('layouts/{0}.kv'.format("error"))

        Builder.apply(self.root)

        self.root.add_widget(self.view)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MainApp().run()
```

The sample kv dynamic string which gets passed as an API call is:

```
<CountdownTimer>:
    face: face
    ticks: ticks

    BoxLayout:
        id: face
        size_hint: None, None

        Label:
            text: ticks.time
            font_size: root.height/8
            color: 1,1,1,1

    TimerTicks:
        id: ticks

FloatLayout:
    timer: timer_1    

    CountdownTimer:
        id: timer_1
        pos: root.width/1.42, root.height/2.2
```

Summary of the application flow:

Upon startup the MainApp creates an AppShell object in a different thread.
You don't need to worry about this so much. Essentially AppShell is where all the Flask calls are defined and I can push an http put call into the "on_to_gui_layout_change" method with either the layout_name if i'm just trying to change to a layout already defined locally or with a layout string which is a dynamic kv string passed in (see the kv sample above).

Upon sending the new KV string above the application will call "on_to_gui_layout_change" which eventually will call "change_kv".
"change_kv" will walk the widgets and check if they have a destroy method defined (this is so we can stop any timing events from continuing).
After that it calls "clear_widgets()" and if we've passed in a layout it will attempt to load the new view using load_string. Then the view gets added to the root BoxLayout using "add_widget".

This works fine for the first call. If I debug on the second call CountdownTimer has 2 TimerTicks objects. Subsequent calls increase the number of TimerTicks each time until the application goes bang. The weird thing is if I look in the destroy method for the TimerTicks objects after the "self.parent.clear_widgets()" its parent CountdownTimer always has no children which suggests the widgets are cleared down at this point but whenever the "self.view = Builder.load_string(layout)" gets called it weirdly enough ends up duplicating TimerTicks.

I realize I'm probably not correctly discarding the old view but I don't fully understand the life-cycle and what the appropriate way of doing this would be.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: It's a lot more obvious if for each call you move the position of the timer slightly. Then you can actually see the duplicates stack on top of each other.

e.g.:

```
<CountdownTimer>:
    face: face
    ticks: ticks

    BoxLayout:
        id: face
        size_hint: None, None

        Label:
            text: ticks.time
            font_size: root.height/8
            color: 1,1,1,1

    TimerTicks:
        id: ticks

FloatLayout:
    timer: timer_1    

    CountdownTimer:
        id: timer_1
        pos: root.width/1.3, root.height/2.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kv file includes both a root widget and a normal kv rule, so every time you load it you add another identical rule to the CountdownTimer. All of these identical rules are applied, one after the other, when it's instantiated.

Instead, put the kv for the widget you want to load into its own file (or just a string in the python file).

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks a bunch!. That makes so much more sense now.